# How do you make a 2d histogram graph of binned data?

Tags: python, graph, histogram

I have a list of sizes for every 10 seconds. But instead of just single points, I want to plot a range for each point. Like the example graph I attached.

I tried using `hist2d()` but this makes each point the same shape. My data increases it's spacing as it goes up for example:

```
 d=[0,0.062,0.8,1.1,1.5,2.8,4,7,11,16)
```

**This is the type of graph I want:**

[image: This is the type of graph I want]